# How to set an image to the UIButton in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to set an image to the button
[image]

But every time when I add an image to the button it shows a huge image and the image doesn't fit the button size. Like this: [image]

Comment: Do you want a Title ***and*** an Image? Or just the image?

Comment: Just an image without a title

Comment: You would help yourself by going through some of the basics... In the project you posted, your Stack View has no constraints... you gave your buttons Width and Height constraints in Storyboard, and then you try to give them new constraints in code... you're using the newer "Configuration" buttons in Storyboard, but then using non-configuration methods in code (`.setTitle(...)` / `.setImage(...)` / etc)... you want image only, but you're also setting a Title string... and so on. All of those issues are conflicts which will continue to cause problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
yourButton.clipsToBounds = true
yourButton.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill

// Use setBackgroundImage or setImage
yourButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "yourImage"), for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change button style from 'Plain' to 'Default'

[Click here for the image reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oFxW.png)